# Palindromes that are sum of consecutive squares

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-2.x, palindrome

I have been working on a [Project Euler: 125](https://projecteuler.net/problem=125%20%22Project%20Euler:%20problem%20125), which took me ages to solve. The problem and source are cited below

> The palindromic number 595 is interesting because it can be written as
>   the sum of consecutive squares: 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 + 10^2 + 11^2 +
>   12^2.
>
> There are exactly eleven palindromes below one-thousand that can be
>   written as consecutive square sums, and the sum of these palindromes
>   is 4164. Note that 1 = 0^2 + 1^2 has not been included as this problem
>   is concerned with the squares of positive integers.
>
> Find the sum of all the numbers less than 10^8 that are both
>   palindromic and can be written as the sum of consecutive squares.

I firstly tried to figure out if there were some pattern in the square sums, however i found none. My solution ended sadly up being brute force one.

- 1) Generate all possible palindromes
- 2) Generate all possible values
  of square numbers

1) Is fairly fast however 2) takes (understandably) ages. The code works and gives the correct answer, but it takes ages. I think the problem is memory.

**Is there any faster way of checking whether a palindrome can be written as a sum of consecutive squares?**

Any other suggestions for my code are also welcome. Python 2.7

```
from math import floor
from itertools import count

def palindromic_square_summable(limit):
    """
        Finds all numbers p, such that
            p = n^2 + (n+1)^2 + ... + m^2
        and p is a palindrome. Eg 595 or 55.
    """
    dic = get_quadratic_sums(limit) 
    pal = all_palindromes(2, limit)
    total = 0
    for key in pal:
        try:
            dic[key]
            total += key
        except:
            pass
    return total


def get_palindrome():
    """
        Generator for palindromes.
        Generates palindromes, starting with 0.
        A palindrome is a number which reads the same in both directions.
    """
    yield 0
    for digits in count(1):
        first = 10 ** ((digits - 1) // 2)
        for s in map(str, range(first, 10 * first)):
            yield int(s + s[-(digits % 2)-1::-1])


def all_palindromes(minP, maxP):
    """Get a sorted list of all palindromes in intervall [minP, maxP]."""
    palindrom_generator = get_palindrome()
    palindrome_dict = dict()
    for palindrome in palindrom_generator:
        if palindrome > maxP:
            break
        if palindrome < minP:
            continue
        palindrome_dict[palindrome] = 1
    return palindrome_dict


def get_quadratic_sums(limit):
    """Get a list of all possible square sums"""
    max_square = int(floor( limit**0.5))
    partial_sums = [0]*(max_square+1)
    dic = dict()

    for i in range(1, max_square+1):
        partial_sums[i] = partial_sums[i - 1] + i**2
        for partial in partial_sums[0:i-1]:
            val = partial_sums[i] - partial
            dic[val] = 1
    return dic


if __name__ == '__main__':
    limit = 10**3
    print palindromic_square_summable(limit)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key problem with the performance of your code is `get_quadratic_sums`. This returns all sums of consecutive squares each of which is *individually* below the limit. But the vast majority of this work is wasted, because we are only interested in in sums of consecutive squares where the *sum* is below the limit.

So a very simple change to your code massively improves its performance. Where the code iterates over sums of squares:

```
for partial in partial_sums[0:i-1]:
    val = partial_sums[i] - partial
    dic[val] = 1
```

Iterate in reverse order (so that `val` is increasing) and stop when `val` is too large:

```
for partial in partial_sums[i-2::-1]:
    val = partial_sums[i] - partial
    if val >= limit:
        break
    dic[val] = 1
```

Now it runs in less than a second on my laptop:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:palindromic_square_summable(10**8), number=1)
0.7864874959923327
```

But we can do even better than that. Slicing a list in Python makes a copy of the sliced part of list. We can avoid the copy by iterating over the indices instead:

```
for j in xrange(i-2, -1, -1):
    val = partial_sums[i] - partial_sums[j]
    if val >= limit:
        break
    dic[val] = 1
```

Now it runs in less than half a second:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:palindromic_square_summable(10**8), number=1)
0.40678663086146116
```

A few more improvements:

1. `int` rounds towards zero, so you can write `int(limit ** .5)` instead of `int(floor(limit ** .5))`.
2. Since there have to be at least two squares in the sum, we only need to check up to `int((limit / 2) ** .5)`.
3. `get_quadratic_sums` returns a dictionary whose keys are sums and whose values are always 1. But the values are never used, so it would make more sense to use Python's built-in *sets*:

   ```
   def get_quadratic_sums(limit):
       """Return set of sums below limit of two or more consecutive squares."""
       max_square = int((limit / 2) ** .5) + 1
       partial_sums = [0] * max_square
       sums = set()
       _add = sums.add
       total = 0
       for i in xrange(1, max_square):
           total += i * i
           partial_sums[i] = total
           for j in xrange(i - 2, -1, -1):
               val = total - partial_sums[j]
               if val >= limit:
                   break
               _add(val)
       return sums
   ```

   Note the use of the local variable `_add` to remember the `sums.add` method: this avoids looking it up again on each loop iteration.
4. Similarly, `all_palindromes` can be changed to return a set instead of a dictionary:

   ```
   def all_palindromes(limit):
       """Return set of palindromes below limit."""
       palindromes = set()
       _add = palindromes.add
       for p in get_palindrome():
           if p >= limit:
               break
           _add(p)
       return palindromes
   ```
5. Now that both of these functions return sets, you can just take their intersection, like this:

   ```
   def palindromic_square_summable(limit=10**8):
       """Return the sum of palindromes below limit that are sums of two or
       more consecutive positive integers.

       """
       return sum(get_quadratic_sums(limit) & all_palindromes(limit))
   ```

   This is even faster:

   ```
   >>> timeit(palindromic_square_summable, number=1)
   0.29244883195497096
   ```

Comment: Try change `range` to `xrange` in `def get_quadratic_sums(limit)`

Comment: @vaeta: It doesn't make much difference to the runtime, but as you wish.

Comment: Great answer, your first suggestion hit me in the head as a brick. I was cosidering using sets, but I had the feeling that adding elements to a set is slow and then checking it.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Adding elements to a set is a little slower than adding them to a dictionary (because you have to call a method to add an item to a set whereas there is syntax for adding elements to a dictionary). But with sets there's a substantial speedup at the intersection step that more than compensates for this.